# ExtJS DateField gets blanked out when selected

Tags: extjs, datefield

I have a grid with a Column configured like...

```
{
   ...
   editor:new Ext.form.DateField({format:'m/d/Y'}),
   renderer: function (val){return val ? Ext.util.Format.date(val, 'm/d/Y') : ''}
   ...
}
```

It works fine, except that when I click on a cell to edit it, the cell gets blanked out rather than maintaining its existing value until I choose new one. If after clicking the cell I click away from it, the cell is left empty.

Any idea what would cause this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would have thought you'd want your column defined like this:

```
columns: [{
    xtype: 'datecolumn', 
    format: 'm/d/Y',
    editor: {
        xtype: 'datefield'
    }
}]
```

I don't think you need to use a renderer or use create are you are using it in your example

Comment: Thanks, this is much cleaner, but doesn't solve the specific issue I'm having

Comment: Which version of ExtJS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar problem, and solved it somewhat with setting `allowBlank: false`, as below:

```
...
editor:new Ext.form.DateField({
    format:'m/d/Y',
    allowBlank: false
}),
...
```

This should reset the value back to its original value if you click out of the datefield without selecting a new value.

Comment: How to retain the old value and edit the same rather than , going blank and choosing the new one